# Error Downloading Phonegap From npm

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I am trying to download phonegap via:
`npm install -g phonegap`
yet I keep getting an error and I don't know why. I made sure I had Node.JS downloaded.

> npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found:
>   cordova-lib@'lorinbeer/cordova-li b.git#pg.3.5.0'
>
> npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
>
> npm ERR! notarget ["0.21.2","0.21.3"]
>
> npm ERR! notarget
>
> npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
>
> npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are
>   requesting
>
> npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
>
> npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
>
> npm ERR! command "E:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\Program
>   Files\nod ejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g"
>   "phonegap"
>
> npm ERR! cwd C:\WINDOWS\system32
>
> npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
>
> npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
>
> npm ERR! code ETARGET
>
> npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\WINDOWS\system32\npm-debug.log
>
> npm ERR! not ok code 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install older version:

```
npm install -g phonegap@3.4
```

Comment: Didn't even think about doing this, appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Please view [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083982/phonegap-installation-error-npm). Do everything & finally,

" So you have to `npm install -g cordova-lib` first and rename the line in the package.json to the following: `cordova-lib": "0.21.3",` " suggested by [Ihsan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1989637/ihsan)

Comment: Thank you for this info! Glad to see it isn't just an issue I'm facing. I didn't want to mess anything up more, so I just went with the past version fix. We are using 3.3 (Maybe try 3.4 again) due to an issue with 3.4 so it works anyways.