# install PhoneGap 3.x

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

when install PhoneGap 3.X using npm, recieve some Errors, like (image below):

[image: installation of PhoneGap]

note: I NodeJS already installed

Comment: Did you install your sdk?

Comment: what you mean, (just install node.js) follow PhoneGaph.com steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing older version:

```
npm install -g phonegap@3.4
```

However if you want to install latest version. Follow steps suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24100175/2741586).

> ```
> Download the zip of phonegap-cli repo (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/archive/master.zip)
> Unzip it
> Open the package.json file and find the cordova-lib entry in dependencies (line 32)
> Change the value to 0.21.3 which is the last version.
> Recreate an archive of the folder to the tar.gz format
>
> Open your CLI and run this command:
>
> npm install -g path/to/archive/phonegap-cli-master.tar.gz
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the version number while installing. For instance:

```
npm install -g phonegap@3.4
```

Hope, this will help you.