# How do I install the BarcodeScanner plugin in PhoneGap?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

All I want to do is use this plugin (https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner) in a single page with a link that activates the scanner.

I was hoping someone could tell me the exact CLI command I need to run to get the most basic barcode scanning to work on at least android

Here is what I have been trying but the last 2 days resulted in me determining I am an idiot, or this whole phonegap thing is a mess.

Here is what I have been trying:

1. `phonegap create BarcodeTest`
2. `cd BarcodeTest`
3. `phonegap build android`
4. Then I download the zip of the Barcode scanner project. Using the URL or plugin ID either fails completely, or uses an old version of the BarcodeScanner plugin I unzip the folder
5. plugman install --platform android --project ./platforms/android --plugin

When I build and load the resulting android project in ADT, debugging gives me this error:
Uncaught module cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner not found at file:///android_asset/www/phonegap.js:59

I made sure to include the plugin reference like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="barcodescanner.js"></script>
```

But it still does not help

I know there were some recent issues ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083982/phonegap-installation-error-npm)) regarding the latest 3.5 version of PhoneGap, but I have no idea of PhoneGap/Cordova/Plugins/Plugman are out of synch, or I have to mix and match commands or I am just plain wrong

Due to the issue I am still having, I could only install PhoneGap 3.4.

Any documentation I found telling me to use the "cordova" command does not work as that command is not installed (I thought I am now using PhoneGap?!?!)

Comment: Try `cordova plugin add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git` and then `cordova build android` NOTE: you may need to create a new project first

Comment: I don't have the cordova command available, but I was able to use `phonegap plugin add`. But I am still having the same error.  But I did notice that, unlike plugman, the plugin add command first downloads the plugin to the root project for all available platforms.  plugman requires that you specify a platform when installing the plugin.  Which is the right way?

Comment: There is some compatiablity issues I found with phonegap cli. Use cordova for exceptional results. install cordova cli using `npm install cordova -g`